# Proving that, for every $\theta \in \mathbb Q$, $\sin(n!\theta\pi)$ has a limit, using $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

> If $\theta \in \mathbb Q$, show that $\{\sin(n!\theta\pi)\}$ has a limit

How can I rigorously prove that this sequence has a limit using $\epsilon-N$? Is it even possible to do so?

I know that we can write $\theta$ as ${p \over q}, p \in \mathbb Z, q \in \mathbb N,$. Hence, as $n\to\infty$, we have that $n!$ is the product of all natural numbers meaning that $q | n!$.

But can we choose $N = q > 0$? Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $n\ge N$, $q|n!$, and we get that $$\begin{align}|\sin(n!\theta\pi) - 0| &= \left|\sin \left(n!{p \over q}\pi\right)\right| \\ &\le |\sin(k\pi)| \tag{Since $q|n!$, then $N!(p/q) = k\in\mathbb Z$} \\ & = 0 < \epsilon\end{align}$$

Comment: Your proof seems correct.

Comment: to be honest i think your proof is much nicer and more elegant then some cumbersome epsilon-delta argument (+1)

Comment: Your proof is fine. You may even shorten it by just saying that the sequence is ultimately constant $(=0)$, whatever $\theta\in{\mathbb Q}$.